# Grouping array values Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following:

```
[
{year: 2017, week: 45},
{year: 2017, week: 46},
{year: 2017, week: 47},
{year: 2017, week: 48},
{year: 2017, week: 50},
{year: 2017, week: 52},
{year: 2018, week: 1},
{year: 2018, week: 2},
{year: 2018, week: 5}
]
```

But want to group it by year into this format:

```
[
  { 2017 : [{
     label: 45, value: 45,
     label: 46, value: 46,
     label: 47, value: 47,
     label: 48, value: 48,
     etc
  },
  { 2018 : [{
     label: 1, value: 1,
     label: 2, value: 2,
     etc
  }]
]
```

What's the best way to do this using Javascript(ES6)? I can use lodash/underscore libraries too.

Comment: please add a valid result. (and what you have tried.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce`

```
var output = arr.reduce((a, b) => ((a[b.year] = a[b.year] || []).push({
  label: b.week,
  val: b.week
}), a), {});
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    year: 2017,
    week: 45
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    week: 46
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    week: 47
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    week: 48
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    week: 50
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    week: 52
  },
  {
    year: 2018,
    week: 1
  },
  {
    year: 2018,
    week: 2
  },
  {
    year: 2018,
    week: 5
  }
];

var output = arr.reduce((a, b) => (a[b.year] = a[b.year] || [], a[b.year].push({
  label: b.week,
  val: b.week
}), a), {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You should replace `a[b.year] = a[b.year] || [], a[b.year]` with `(a[b.year] || [])`.

Comment: @RobG Not exactly since it will still have to assign it back to `a[b.year]`, but still a good spot and I have included the same.

Comment: Does what i needed it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and use the reference to the array for inserting a new object.

```js
var data = [{ year: 2017, week: 45 }, { year: 2017, week: 46 }, { year: 2017, week: 47 }, { year: 2017, week: 48 }, { year: 2017, week: 50 }, { year: 2017, week: 52 }, { year: 2018, week: 1 }, { year: 2018, week: 2 }, { year: 2018, week: 5 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    var temp = {};
    if (!hash[o.year]) {
        hash[o.year] = [];
        temp[o.year] = hash[o.year];
        result.push(temp);
    }
    hash[o.year].push({ label: o.week, value: o.week });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why `Object.create(null)` instaed of `{}` ?? :)

Comment: because it could be some prototypes as key.

Answer (score 0):

it will be helpful to you

```js
var arr=[
{year: 2017, week: 45},
{year: 2017, week: 46},
{year: 2017, week: 47},
{year: 2017, week: 48},
{year: 2017, week: 50},
{year: 2017, week: 52},
{year: 2018, week: 1},
{year: 2018, week: 2},
{year: 2018, week: 5}
]
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
       (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
         return rv;
    }, {});
};
var arr_res=groupBy(arr, 'year')
console.log(arr_res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` and `Array.from`:

I've made an assumption about your requirement as what you have requested is not valid object.

```
const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((accum, val) => {
  const grouping = accum.get(val.year) || [];
  grouping.push({ label: val.week, value: val.week });
  accum.set(val.year, grouping);
  return accum;
}, new Map()), kv => ({ [kv[0]]: kv[1] }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)